# Retrieving behind the refrigerator

Tags: kitchen

My dishwashing soap fell through a gap and went behind my refrigerator. I took a broom and got it to stand upright but I don't know how I can get it out. I can't pull my fridge out as it's in there tight so my only option is to go behind and there is only about 3 inches. Any suggestions on getting it from there?

Comment: A long ruler? How far do you need to reach?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how much of a hack it is, but I have one of these...

[image: FLexible grabber]

Known as "flexible grabbers", these are easily available from decent hardware shops or online.
They are specifically for getting stuff from behind radiators or under fridges.

A spring-loaded claw on the end will grip the offending item, although it can sometimes be fiddly to get enough grip to pull something up.

Answer (score 1):

Use a strong long wire with a hook at the end. And a good supply of patience.

Comment: A wire coat hanger comes to mind as a source for a strong long wire with a hook at the end. Somewhere, there's a bag of patience lying around near here.

Answer (score 1):

Make a lasso to grab the dishwashing soap container.

You should be able to grab the container by tying a loop in a light cord and threading the free end through the loop to make a slip knot.

Tie or tape (better) the loop end of your lasso to the broom handle and drop the loop around the container behind the refrigerator.

[image: broomstick lasso grabber hack]

When the loop is positioned around the container, pull the free end of the lasso to tighten the loop around the soap container and pull the container free.

Good luck.

Comment: Great solution, broom handle to position and loop and cord to tighten it to grab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a walking stick or back scratcher they may help you get something from behind a frig.I have used a curtain rod when I needed something longer.